# Two people working on the same file using GitHub

Tags: git, github

Me and my colleague are both working on the same file. While I was working on my local machine, he made some other changes to the same file and pushed them to the remote repository.

What is the right approach in this situation if we need to have both his and my changes pushed? I would like to have both our work merge but I'm not sure if that's possible. Also, I would like to avoid overwriting anything he has done so far.

Answer (score 2):

Commit your stuff when it's done, but don't push it to remote. Then run

```
git pull --rebase
```

This will replay all the commits on remote, and place your local commits on top. This way you won't have to deal with ugly merge commits.

There might be conflicts, but git marks the specific blocks to help you solve them.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead with fetching/merging. Solve conflicts/commit if they arise. Push the end result. That's the way (well, at least one of them) it's to be done.